# Render is blank gray screen

Tags: rendering

I've tried everything, but the render of my scene is just a blank gray screen. I've checked off "sequencer", made sure the composite node is connected, also checked all the items in my outliner to show up on final render, and have added lights to the scene. The camera is in line with the scene view too. When I preview "Rendered" in the viewport, everything looks the way it should, but once I hit "Render image", I get nothing but a blank screen. This is both for cycles/evee....Does anyone have any more suggestions?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: might be lots of reasons....search here for black screen or black render...and if that doesn't help, provide blend file so we can check it out